# How to remove Counter from .Net 8 Blazor template

Tags: blazor

I just created my first .Net 8 Blazor Web App using the new template.  I want to remove the Counter, as I will be modifying the app for my own purposes.  I run into a problem when I remove the last line of the following boilerplate code:

```
    app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
        .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
        .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
        .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Counter).Assembly);
```

Remove that line, then run the app and you get a 404.  Put it back, and it runs fine.

How do I get rid of the counter code? It's driving me nuts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at that line. It says `typeof(Counter).Assembly`.

You're not removing counter, your removing the instruction for the SSR Razor/Blazor to read any routes [defined by "@page ..."] in the assembly to which `Counter` belongs.

That line:

```cs
.AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Counter).Assembly);
```

Needs to refer any object in the Client Project.

In this example the solution is called `SO77672168` [your question ID].

This line:

```cs
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(SO77672168.Client._Imports).Assembly);
```

Adds the middleware to the Http request pipeline, and instructs the server side router to not only look in it's own assembly for routes, but also in the assembly to which `SO77672168.Client._Imports` belongs.

Comment: Thank you, that made sense.  I figured it had to do with adding assemblies, and I even tried just "AddAdditionalAssemblies()".  It just wasn't clear why "Counter" was in there specifically. 

Just for further clarification, the "typeof" it needs is any THING where THING = @page="THING" 

Do I understand that right?

Or, you said any object in the client project, so that could be even the _Imports.razor??

I ask, because if that is true, then I might make a PR for Microsoft to change the template :)

Comment: Of course, I could just try (and I did) using "_Imports" in the typeof area and find that it doesn't work.  I also tried "Program" and that didn't work.  Then I tried MainLayout.razor and that DID work...  So, I'm still not 100% clear on the requirements for what goes into the typeof

Comment: Any class or object defined in the Client project assembly.